# Can't find members of group using its cn in LDAP

Tags: ldap, ldap-query

I am totally new to LDAP, and have just started. I have seen a couple of examples, which to my understanding have used the query as I have done, but in my case it seems to be not working.

I have a hierarchy like this (I am using Apache Directory Studio):

[image]

If I double click on the object with `ou=scientists` then its info will pop up as followed:
[image]

So this group with `ou=scientists` has a `cn=Scientists` (I have checked and there are no following spaces after Scientists.

I want to simply find stuff inside the group with `ou=scientists`.
There is 1 way to do it like this:
`ou=scientists,dc=example,dc=com` which gives the expected result.
[image]

But I want to be able to find the content inside the group with `ou=scientists` not by its `ou` value, but by its `cn` value. So I thought to myself, ok I can use this: `cn=Scientists,dc=example,dc=com`

But this yields 0 results. I think I am missing a key point here. What should I actually do?

Comment: I am using a server as mentioned here: https://www.forumsys.com/tutorials/integration-how-to/ldap/online-ldap-test-server/

Comment: The distinguished name of the object is `ou=scientists,dc=example,dc=com`. That's the only way you can refer to it without a search. To find it based on its `commonName` value, you would need to perform an LDAP search operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple things to consider when you query a LDAP directory.

In your case you want to lookup from a branch (call search base dn in LDAP) and apply a filter in all the childrens of this branch to select those you want :

`ldapsearch ... -b <search base dn> -s sub "<FILTER>"`

So for your DIT :

`ldapsearch ... -b dc=example,dc=com -s sub "(&(objectClass=groupOfUniqueNames)(cn=scientists))"`

Consider learning how the search request works in LDAP if you want to work more deeply with ldap : https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/SearchRequest

Answer (score 0):

@SeanGoudarzi I think there is some misunderstanding about how LDAP model works.
If you want to find Sub-entries of a given entry, you need 2 searches.
One to find the base-entry and one to find the child entries

To find entry with so called 'relative distinguished name' `ou=scientists` you need a search like

```
ldapsearch ... -b dc=example,dc=com -s sub cn=scientists dn
```

and then

```
ldapsearch ... -b DN_RESULT_FORM_PREVIOUS_SEARCH -s one objectclass=* dn
```

this will give you

```
dn: ou=italians,ou=scientiests,dc=example,dc=com
```

Or do you want to achieve something else?